# Upload file to IBM COS with Python Flask

Tags: python, image, amazon-s3, cloud, trigonometry

I'm building a cloud foundry application on IBM server, deployed with IBM toolchain and using python.
I need to upload a photo on the IBM COS (Cloud object storage) and the function that do it is:

```
upload_large_file(bucket, filename, path_to_file)
```

Until now, I have created a HTML page and an upload button. Then I take the photo, pass it through an ajax request to a Flask page.
I have uploaded correctly the photo on the server built in with my application (https://my-app-url/upload/photo.png), but I'm not able to find the path of the image.

Does anybody have some ideas?